# error importing json data to mongo

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm trying to import some json data into Mongo and keep getting an error. I'm doing the import like this

```
mongoimport --stopOnError --db s  --collection names  < snow.json
```

The error it's giving me is

```
 Failure parsing JSON string near: ,

exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: Failure parsing JSON string near: ,
```

this is the json data. There's actually more (about 9) entries, but i get the error even when there's two. I copied this format from another json file that I was able to import. Running it through the json validator says

```
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

around the end of the first entry, but it says the same thing for the file I imported successfully too. Can you tell me what's wrong?

```
{ "firstname" : "Dave", "initial" : "M", "lastname" : "Smore", "firm" : "", "address" : "PO Box 479, Vancouver BC V1L 5R3", 
"email" : "david@smore.ca", "phone" : "(250) 654-6840" , "fax" : "(456) 987-7370", "sex": "m"} 

{ "firstname" : "Kerry", "initial" : "C", "lastname" : "Amber", "firm" : "K Amber Corporation", 
"address" : "980 5th Ave, Snowbank, BC V2L 3H8", "email" : "kamber@gmail.com", "phone" : "604 622 6156" , "fax" : "604 662-4532", "sex": "f"}
```

Comment: Do you have linebreaks inside the JSON representations?

Comment: I had that issue too with NoSQLUnit. The example Json worked there and mine didn't. I couldn't see what was wrong with it (dropped NoSQLUnit completely so can't tell whats wrong with it). Both files contained line breaks. So maybe the problem is with some special line break (\r\n or \n)?

Comment: With the example that you have provided i checked what happening end i got the same error when i inserted a \n and nothing when i removed all line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @attish, the import worked after I removed line breaks from the json file.